# how can I add more validation for password input when using react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am making a simple user registration page with only 3 fields, Email, password and repeat-password.

I have some conditions for the password to be accepted for example it should not contain the following letters: "e" "k" "n" "m", it should be between 6 and 11 letters and also there are more validation like the first letter needs to be a Capitol letter, and the rest lower case letters.

I have so far made a simple react application with email and password, some of the validations works for example the length but I am not sure how to add the other validations and if I know I think I need to use ASCII to convert letters to number so I can make the comparison.

```
validateField(fieldName, value) {
    let fieldValidationErrors = this.state.formErrors;
    let emailValid = this.state.emailValid;
    let passwordValid = this.state.passwordValid;
    switch(fieldName) {
      case 'email':
        emailValid = value.match(/^([\w.%+-]+)@([\w-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})$/i);
        fieldValidationErrors.email = emailValid ? '' : ' is invalid';
        break;
      case 'password':
        passwordValid = value.length >= 6 &&  value.length <= 11;
        fieldValidationErrors.password = passwordValid ? '': ' is not valid';
        //fieldValidationErrors.password = passwordValid.includes('e') ? '': 'contains i';
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    this.setState({formErrors: fieldValidationErrors,
                    emailValid: emailValid,
                    passwordValid: passwordValid
                  }, this.validateForm);
  }
```

Comment: Putting so many restrictions on the password makes it weak.

Comment: @marekful its just for a test!

Comment: can you please describe exact restrictions you want to put for your password validation. for example                                                                                        
   1. should be between 6 and 11 letters;                                                          
   2. ....                        so that i could work on it

Answer (score 0):

```js
function check(value){
  return (value.length >= 6 &&  value.length <= 11) && (value.match(/[e,k,n,m]/) === null) || /^[A-Z][a-z]+$/.test(value)
}

console.log(check("asdfg"))
console.log(check("Asdfg"))
console.log(check("aDdfg"))
console.log(check("Asdfgee"))
```

this contains all your three checks,

```
var passwordValid = (value.length >= 6 &&  value.length <= 11) && (value.match(/[e,k,n,m]/) === null) || /^[A-Z][a-z]+$/.test(value)
```

Comment: How does this last part work? /^[A-Z][a-z]+$/.test(value)

Comment: Last part checks the string against a regex, which says that first letter should be capital and after that all letters smaller case.

Comment: how do I chek for only capital letter (to see if evey letter is capital) or the same for lowercase letters, and what if I want to add other validations more specifies one, for example I want to see if I have at least 2 letters that are after each other like "xy" or "op" and what if I want to see for example if I have exactly or more 2 letters of "a"?

Comment: What do you think? Add more checks for your requirements.

Comment: thanks I made it, but another validation is to see if I have at least 2 letter in a row  like xy or op, how can I make this validation, can u give me some tips?

Comment: Use regex, you can use a check like, `/(xy|op)/`

Comment: but you dont what are the letters you just want to see if we have this combination in out password as well, how can I use any regex for that? do I have to make my own, or when u want to have some pairs in your password and you want to see if you have already in the password to accepts, then again should I use regex ? do u understand what I mean?